# Tomcat9 as windows service or startup.bat

Tags: windows, tomcat

when i start tomcat as a windows service, there are major commands i cannot run within my servlet.
running tomcat using the bin/startup.bat file works fine.

what is the key difference, and how can i get the tomcat (as windows service) run with the same privilege of the startup bat?

for instance running the below script runs only if i start tomcat with the startup script.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "java HelloWorldToPDF "+code+"");
pb.directory(new File("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 9.0\\webapps\\stock\\WEB-INF\\classes\\"));
Process process = pb.start();
```

currently tomcat9 is being launched as a windows service with local system account.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding with running anything under Windows as a service is that you need to ensure you have the correct permissions for the service account that's running the service.  In your case, you need to make sure the local system account has access to the 'major commands'.